# Can't access some sites with any browser on windows 10 on a particular isp

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, dns, microsoft-edge

I can't access some websites like edx.org,onlinesbi.com,whatsmydns.net on chrome,firefox or edge on windows 10 brand new pc (can be accessed over tor), when tried to access through a particular isp over wifi. I can access these same sites on android phone over same isp over wifi.

These same sites can be accessed when wifi is switched to different isp over hotspot on the windows 10 pc.

Tried flushing dns , changing dns to 8.8.8.8 etc

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: If it doesn't work with a particular ISP, it seems they are either deliberately blocked or there is a routing problem.

Comment: Get in touch with Support of that ISP and try to explain the problem. You might need to insist on a technical person.

Comment: ERR_TIMED_OUT on chrome

Comment: over the same isp these sites are accessible on my android phone...

Comment: Okay problem solved. Told isp about the problem and as per instruction changed my router MTU settings. Previously it was 1492, now changed to 1480.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody facing this type of situation, try changing MTU setting in your router.
I changed mine from 1492 to 1480.